# Memory leaks from GenServer processes

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, elixir, gen-server

I have been into a little trouble lately: The memory used by GenServer processes is super high, probably because of large binary leaks.

The problem comes from here: we receive large binaries through the GenServer and we pass them to the consumer, which then interacts with that data. Now, these large binaries are never assigned to a variable and the GC doesn't go over them.

I have tried hibernating the processes after managing the data, which partially worked because the memory used by processes lowered a lot, but since binaries were not getting GC'd, the amount of memory used by them increased slowly but steadily, from 30 MBs without hibernating to 200MBs with process hibernation in about 25 minutes.

I have also tried to set `:erlang.system_flag(:fullsweep_after, 0)`, which has also worked and lowered the memory used by processes by around 20%.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWeRO.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nWo.png).
*I must say it goes down to 60-70MB used by processes from time to time.*

*Edit: Using :recon.bin_leak(15) frees [a lot of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83LqW.png) -- [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/xsj5sb94) of :recon.bin_leak(15)*

Anyhow the memory used is still high and I'm completely sure it can be fixed.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1HKf.png) you have a screenshot taken from the observer in the Processes tab. As you can see, GenServer is the one eating the memory like the cookie monster.

I have researched a lot about this topic, tried all the suggestions and possible solutions that were given out there, and nevertheless, I am still in this position.

Any help is welcome.

The code is in [this Github Repository](https://github.com/satom99/coxir)

[Code of interest](https://github.com/satom99/coxir/tree/master/lib/coxir/stage) that is probably causing this + [Applications tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZYHI.png). *3 out of 4 processes there (<0.294.0>, <0.295.0>, <0.297.0> are using [27MB of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1dBa.png)*.

Thank you beforehand for reading.

Comment: Just looking at this, but this has a bit of code smell to it: https://github.com/satom99/coxir/blob/master/lib/coxir/stage/middle.ex#L99-L104  Have you been able to isolate where the leak is coming from? Perhaps time the execution of all your functions? Its hard to diagnose the entire pipeline, but to me it seems to be coming from the producer consumer.

Comment: Did you try copying messages with `:binary.copy/1`?

Comment: I have seen that lowering the amount of created Middles lowered the memory usage a lot. About copying messages with `:binary.copy/1`, how would I apply that in my situation?

Botonomous, I added a `buffer_size` to the [producer_consumer](https://github.com/satom99/coxir/pull/25/files#diff-2ff44e3f492cc3dd6cd17d282cfbd9ffR15) and that has lowered the memory used by a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the `:hibernate` atom to your `handle_events` return values in your GenStage related modules. For example:

```
def handle_events(events, _from, %{handler: handler, public: public} = state) do
  public = handle(handler, events, public)
  {:noreply, [], %{state | public: public}, :hibernate}
end
```

Another option is to record the PIDs after `:recon.bin_leak()` and then pass them to `Process.info(PID)` to get some more information about the offending GenServers.

Some additional resources:
https://elixirforum.com/t/extremely-high-memory-usage-in-genservers/4035/23

https://www.erlang-in-anger.com/ (Specifically Chapter 7 on Memory Leaks)